# Perl url encoding using Curl

Tags: perl, http, curl

I am having an issue where I am using cURL inside a perl script to execute a http request. I believe my issue is related to special characters in the URL string but I cannot figure out how to make it work.

I can confirm that the URL is correct as I can run it from my browser.

My perl script is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

$url = "http://machine/callResync?start=2017-02-01 00.00.00.000&end=2017-02-01 23.23.999";

system "curl $url
```

It fails when it reaches the first whitespace. I tired to escape that using %20.

After that I put in %26 to escape the & but then I get another issue. I have tired a number of different combinations but it keeps failing.

Any idea's.

Comment: Why you do not use a perl module like: [WWW:Curl](http://search.cpan.org/~szbalint/WWW-Curl-4.17/lib/WWW/Curl.pm) instead of a system call

Comment: You don't need to escape the `&`. That's part of the URL.

Comment: Pass the arguments to `system` with an array.

Comment: @ceving: That's not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`URI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI) module to correctly build a URL, and rather than shelling out to cURL you should use a Perl library like [`LWP::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Simple) to access the page

The disadvantage of `LWP::Simple` is that it may be *too* simple in that it provides no diagnostics if the transaction fails. If you find you need something more elaborate then you should look at
[`HTTP::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Tiny),
[`LWP::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent), or
[`Mojo::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent).
If you need help with these then please ask

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use URI;
use LWP::Simple 'get';

my $url = URI->new('http://machine/callResync');
$url->query_form(
    start => '2017-02-01 00.00.00.000',
    end   => '2017-02-01 23.23.999',
);

my $content = get($url) or die "Failed to access URL";
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem number 1: You used an invalid URL. Spaces can't appear in URLs.

```
my $url = "http://machine/callResync?start=2017-02-01%2000.00.00.000&end=2017-02-01%2023.23.999";
```

---

Problem number 2: Shell injection error. You didn't correctly form your shell command.

```
system('curl', $url);
```

or

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $cmd = shell_quote('curl', $url);
system($cmd);
```